# C# Cannot change return value?

Tags: c#, variables, struct

I'm a little hung on C# structs. I have the following code extract (sorry for the mass - i reduced as much as possible):

```
namespace Generics
{
    public struct Generic
    {
        public struct Traverse
        {
            public double TraverseWidth, CurrentPosition;
        }
    }

    public class XXXSettings
    {
        private Generics.Generic.Traverse _TRAVERSE;

        public Generics.Generic.Traverse TraverseData
        {
            get { return _TRAVERSE; }
            set { this._TRAVERSE = TraverseData; }
        }

        public XXXSettings()
        {
            _TRAVERSE = new Generics.Generic.Traverse() { CurrentPosition = 0, TraverseWidth = 0 };
        }
    }
}

namespace XXX_Driver
{
    public class XXXClient
    {
        private Generics.XXXSettings _Settings;

        public Generics.XXXSettings Settings
        {
            get { return _Settings; }
            set { this._Settings = Settings; }
        }
        public bool Connect()
        {
            if (this.Settings == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException();
            }

            Settings.TraverseData.TraverseWidth = "1234";

        }
    }
}
```

My problem: The last line of code

```
Settings.TraverseData
```

is marked as "The return value of XXXSettings.TraverseData can not be changed because it is no variable."

But why is this? I'm used to structs from VB.NET and don't know this behavior?!

Even

```
_Settings.TraverseData.TraverseWidth = new Generics.Generic.Traverse() { TraverseWidth = 1234, CurrentPosition = 0 };
```

won't help. Is there at least ANY use for structs in C#? I thought it's a conglomerate of values but if they're not accessible?!

Thanks for some explaination and some hints, how I should change my code :)

Comment: Can you try:  public struct Traverse
        {
            public double TraverseWidth {get;set;} public double CurrentPosition {get;set;}
        }

Comment: Off-topic: Have you used `struct` in C# before? They behave a little different then a `class`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`structs` do not behave the way you'd expect. They are *immutable*.

```
var myStruct = new Struct { Name = "Rob", Gender = "m" };
myStruct.Name = "Test";
```

This code creates a struct with the Name "Rob". Then, it creates a *new* struct, copies the values over, except for `Name`, which it sets to `Test`.

Now, the reason you're having this error is because you're using a *property*, not a field or variable. .NET only performs this 'copy-and-replace' automatically for variables.

There are two ways to fix your code...  use a field (not the best approach):

```
public Generic.Traverse TraverseData;
```

Or, use `class` instead of `struct` - **This approach is probably better suited to you.**

Use structs sparingly. It's almost never a good idea to change a property of a struct, they're meant to be immutable. And, while you're learning `C#`, it's very unlikely you'll need to use a struct instead of a class.

VB has the same behavior, as shown here:

```
Sub Main
    Dim a as A
    a = new A()
    a.Prop2.Name = "A"
End Sub

Structure Test
    public Name as String
End Structure

Class A
    public property Prop2 As Test = new Test()
End Class
```

Gives the error

> Expression is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment.

Changing it to `public Prop2 As Test = new Test()` (or using a class instead of struct) works as expected.

Comment: Umph that sounds plausible. 

Coming from the VB corner there's a huge difference to C# - even though they are said to bo pretty equal besides the syntax...

Comment: @AllDayPiano VB also has the same behavior - I'll add a snippet of code for VB

Comment: The initial part of the answer is totally wrong. Whether `struct` (or `class`) is immutable depends exactly on how you'll make it. Also the "copy and replace` part for `struct` fields - it doesn't work this way.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, `TraverseData`  is not a variable :

```
public Generics.Generic.Traverse TraverseData
{
    get { return _TRAVERSE; }
    set { this._TRAVERSE = TraverseData; } // Mistake is here !!
}
```

Use `value` keyword to retrieve the actual set value :

```
public Generics.Generic.Traverse TraverseData
{
    get { return _TRAVERSE; }
    set { this._TRAVERSE = value; } 
}
```

Comment: Well thanks for you fast response. It was certainly a mistake, but intelli-sense does still claim the line to be wrong :-|